# Rutherfords alpha scattering conclutions?

Tags: radiation, atoms

Please can some one give me rutherfords observations and his conclutions from each onbservation, I have looked in text books but they only give them sepratly with no direct link betweeen which observation led to which conclution thus this is what i am looking for. THanks

Comment: Rutherford observed a lot of things over the years. Could you be a little more specific about the physics you're asking about?

Comment: Sorry i completely overlooked this, i mean his alpha scattering and determining the size of the nucleus

Comment: For future reference, the right thing to do when someone asks for clarification is to *edit the question*. While posting a short correction in the comments will keep people interested, comments can be deleted without notice, so all important changes should make their way back into the question text. Nor should you open a new "question" for the same question as you have done in this case. I've reversed the usual order of duplicate identification because you got answers on the duplicate.